# android automatic application restart if device is in homescreen and idle for a period of time

Tags: android, restart

I'm writing an app that will be used in public transportation and I have a special requirement for it. I need the app to auto restart/bring to front somehow **if all the following conditions are met**:

-the user presses the back key or the home key and the app is minimized

-a period of time has passed since the device is idle

In conclusion I'd like to know what should I use, broadcast receivers or background services.
Code snippets or examples would be appreciated :) Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register a `BroadcastReceiver for screen_off` action and on it's `onReceive()` method unlock the screen if required and launch your application.